# JQuery Masked Input - mask the first part of a social security number

Tags: jquery, masking, maskedinput

I'm using [jQuery masked input pluigic](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for social security number masking. I want the first 5 characters to be masked like a password. I was able to mask as shown in demos but I am not able to get masking as `XXX-XX-1234`

Need, kind of a password-like masking where the first five characters would be masked with 'X' and the rest will be shown normally. Any direction would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep it simple. You can always mask it in a confirmation page. What if the user made a mistake? How could they tell they typed the correct SSN? I'd revisit that requirement.

Comment: Let's just say at this point of time those requirements are hard to change. appreciate any suggestions to achieve that behavior.

Comment: Yeah that's actually a standard ask from any business that deals with real money and info and not bitcoin. I'm looking into this as well as it should be standard to hide the majority of the numbers on any NPI data. Will let you know if I come across something. The only solution I have implemented involved showing/hiding the input field after blur with another one that just has ***-**-**** as a placeholder.

Comment: Looks like there is a good answer to this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367230/masking-a-social-security-number-input

Answer (score 1):

Though its an old post, but i have had similar requirement and I came up with https://github.com/mishraas/jQuery-SSN-Field-Masking. You may want to have a look at it.

Comment: Please add some code from the link to your post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you need a secure input mask but this is probably going to break most android devices as they seem to have trouble with the standard masked input from DigitalBush. But worth a shot
: http://jqueryscript.nhavungtau.vn/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Mask-Numbers-In-Text-Field-Secure-Number-Mask

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the latest release of jQuery