# SSN masking with "iphone" Style password

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying in a form to format a SSN ,that each time I enter a key it must change to "*" within 2 seconds while leaving the last digit shown. It also should be masked with (999-99-999) format.
For example the final value should be like: " ***-**-***9 " in the input field.

I have tried with [Masked input plugin](https://github.com/mishraas/jQuery-SSN-Field-Masking/blob/master/Demo.html) but it's not turning into "password" like within 2 seconds.

How do you do this with jQuery?

I looked for other Stackoverflow questions like this, but I couldn't find anything like my issue or expectation. Especilally this question [SSN Masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266567/jquery-masked-input-ssn-like-xxx-xx-1234-first-5-characters-would-be-masked-l?rq=1)

```
 $("#ssnId").unmask().maskSSN('999-99-9999', {maskedChar:'*', maskedCharsLength:10});
```

this is my form

```
<input type="text" id="ssn"   class="form-control" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Why downvote please explain

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it is a bad question. Anyway, here is a jquery plugin that masks the last digit after time: https://github.com/timmywil/password123 Maybe you can combine it with one of the other plugins.

Comment: What is that last bit of code you posted? Is that what you have tried to do? Perhaps explain a bit more what you have tried  already.

Comment: @willdanceforfun I have tried https://github.com/mishraas/jQuery-SSN-Field-Masking/blob/master/Demo.html  this plugin, and it's  working well  with masking and formatting but i need is,  after i enter a value it should shown for a moment and replace with "*" within 2 seconds. i don't know how to do that with this plugin.

Comment: You should make a working demo with jsfiddle or codepen. It will help get a better idea of what is and what isn't working.